# Not To Start MySql Automatically at Centos Startup

Tags: mysql, centos, startup, centos6, vps

i have "CentOS 6" VPS and i wanted to start mysql service automatically at Startup of Server when it is restarted. so i used this command in putty

```
chkconfig --level 345 mysqld on
```

this command is working and mysql starts on every startup automatically. 
BUT how can i now stop this? what if i want to start Mysql manually on every startup, then what command should i use? 
also what is the File where i can see the list of programs that are running automatically on every setup. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off auto-start with this command:

```
chkconfig --level 345 mysqld off
```

To see what is configured for auto-start, you can run:

```
chkconfig --list
```

See more info on chkconfig here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-services-chkconfig.html

Comment: Thanks you Sir for such a useful answer. is there also any File for list of "chkconfig --list" ? to get it with Filezila